# When $\Sigma^{\infty}Y^{\wedge}_p\simeq (\Sigma^{\infty} Y)^{\wedge}_p$?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, bousfield-localization

When studying the stable homotopy of $BG^{\wedge}_p$, with $G$ a finite group, authors know that this abuse of notation is not dangerous because $\Sigma^{\infty}BG^{\wedge}_p$ and $(\Sigma^{\infty}BG)^{\wedge}_p$ are stable homotopy equivalent. However, that abuse is also common when $G$ is a compact Lie group, I do not know any reference that justifies this abuse unlike the finite group case (in this case  $\Sigma^{\infty}BG^{\wedge}_p$ and $(\Sigma^{\infty}BG)^{\wedge}_p$ are not always stable homotopy equivalent).

What is more, some result such as the following from [*a Chun-Nip Lee's article*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00004332):

Let $Y_1, Y_2$ be connected CW complexes such that both $H^{\ast}(Y_1, \mathbb{F}_p )$
and $H^{\ast}(Y_2, \mathbb{F}_p )$ are finitely generated as graded rings. Then the image of the ring
homomorphism
$\{(Y_1)^{\wedge}_p,(Y_2)^{\wedge}_p\}\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{F}_p} (\widetilde{H}^{\ast}(Y_1, \mathbb{F}_p ), \widetilde{H}^{\ast}(Y_1, \mathbb{F}_p ))$
is finite.

What did the author mean by $(Y_i)^{\wedge}_p$?. In general, is there a criterion to know whether $\Sigma^{\infty}Y^{\wedge}_p\simeq (\Sigma^{\infty} Y)^{\wedge}_p$ or not?

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07633

Comment: @skd Thanks, that article proves that $\Sigma^{\infty} (BS^{1})^{\wedge}_p$ is not $p$-complete, what made me think that $BG^{\wedge p}$ in the stable homotopy context means $(\Sigma^{\infty} BG)^{\wedge p}$, although it seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: @VictorTC Unfortunately those kinds of notations are wildly inconsistent from paper to paper (especially when you go to somewhat old ones). There's not much to do but be extra careful.

Comment: When in doubt interpret $\Sigma^\infty(X_p)$ as $(\Sigma^\infty X)_p$. Or, rather, interpret it as $(\Sigma^\infty X_p)_p$, which is equivalent to $(\Sigma^\infty X)_p$. So this is a functor that you can apply to $p$-complete spaces. (How generally are they equivalent? If you're using $\mathbb Z/p$-localization, it's easy to see that they're always equivalent. If you're using $p$-completion, I'm not sure if it's always equivalent, but usually you're using it because in that case it's equivalent to $\mathbb Z/p$-localization.)